# Drop Down Option Value resets are page reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hy Stackoverflow members.
  Here is my little problem, I have a page that I'm saving some values in sessions. For example I have a sorting drop down option for my users.

```
<form id="formName" action="Index.php" method="POST">
    <select name="Sort_Ads" id="Sort_Ads" onchange="document.getElementById('formName').submit()">
        <option>Most Recent Ads</option>
        <option>Price: Low to High</option>
        <option>Price: High to Low</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Once a option is selected the page reloads and the users can see the ads by the selected sorting option.Some php code is working behind it. But with javascript I want to create a function which will set the selected option by users after page reloads. please my javascript skills aren't good enough. Could someone do it I'll be really thank full!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cookie the user to maintain state or use php to parse the selected option as selected.  HTTP is state-less.

ie, you can do something like:

```
var myselection;
$("#Sort_Ads").change(function(){ 
   myselection = $("Sort_Ads option:selected").val();
});
```

call and have a set and read cookie function passing in the myselection var.  w3 schools has a good example of this.

Or, what i would say is the better method, you can use php to print the form, but you'll need to give your options values, and then iterate through each value and if value == selected, change

```
<option value='x'>
```

to

```
 <option value='x' selected>
```

when printing the form.

Comment: Sorry bro, Can you do a cookie script for me please i did't get it at all. I don't know java script.

Comment: You will never learn if you don't at least try.   There's function samples to use:   http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp   I showed you how to get the value of your form above.   now, simply set that myselection value to save to a cookie.    Using the checkcookie function, you can then see if there is one set, and if so, in the onload event, set the selected INdex to the one you want it default to.

$("Sort_Ads").prop('selectedIndex',cookiecheckvalue);